# Is any finite-dimensional extension of a field, say $F$, algebraic and finitely generated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

As title, 
Is any finite-dimensional extension of a field, say $F$, algebraic and finitely generated?

Say if $K/F$ is a finite extension when $K$ is a finite-dimensional vector space of $F$. Clearly, this implies that $K$ is finitely generated (as an algebra) over $F$, since a basis is a generating set. So every finite extension is finitely generated.

So indeed they all are, is my logic correct?

Comment: If $K/F$ is separable, then the Primitive Element Theorem further claims that $K = F(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha\in K$.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

By definition, a field extension of finite degree is finitely generated because the degree *is* the number of linearly independent "vectors" in the extension required to form a spanning set.

Now let $K/F$ be a finite extension.  Consider an arbitrary $a \in K$ and the evaluation homomorphism $\text{ev}_a:F[x] \rightarrow K$ defined such that $g(x) \mapsto g(a)$.  This map cannot be injective because $K$ is finitely generated whereas $F[x]$ is not, so the kernel of this map must be a nontrivial ideal.  This is to say: we can find nontrivial polynomials in $F[x]$ with $a$ as a root for any $a \in K$, namely the nonzero elements of $\ker(\text{ev}_a)$.  In other words, $K/F$ is an algebraic extension.

Comment: A pleasing and efficient answer.

Comment: To me, this answer, as well as the answer from @fretty omit a bit part of what should be in the proof. You crucially state that the map you describe cannot be injective because $K$ is finitely generated whereas $F[x]$ is not. This is not obvious; except in the case where the underlying field $F$ is assumed to be finite (because then we can directly argue via cardinality).  If $F$ is not finite, the cardinality of the domain and codomain can be equal. https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Linearly_Independent/Set provides some very concrete proofs ("proof 3" is especially awesome).

Answer (score 36):

A similar but easier answer to the one given above is as follows.

To show $K/F$ is algebraic if finite we must show that every element of $K$ satisfies a polynomial over $F$.

Suppose $[K : F] = n$ and choose $\alpha\in K$. Then consider the elements $1,\alpha,\alpha^2,...,\alpha^n$.

This is a list of $n+1$ elements in an $n$ dimensional $F$-vector space so must be linearly dependent. Thus there exists $a_0,a_1,...,a_n\in F$ not all zero such that $a_n \alpha^n + ... + a_2\alpha^2 + a_1\alpha + a_0 = 0$.

But then $\alpha$ is a root of the polynomial $a_nx^n + ... + a_2x^2 + a_1x + a_0$ over $F$.

Comment: I like this one a lot.

Comment: c'est élégant !

Comment: Maybe a bit more should be added. It could happen that some of those powers of $\alpha$ are the same. In that case we can't say those are $n+1$ . However it still works considering that the equality $\alpha^i=\alpha^j$ gives us $\alpha$ is a root of $x^i-x^j$ over $F$

Comment: Very nice one, short but precise.

Answer (score 8):

Other answers provide nice proofs, here is a very short one based on the multiplicativity of the degree over field towers: If $ K/F $ is a finite extension and $ \alpha \in K $, then $ F(\alpha) $ is a subfield of $ K $, and we have a tower of fields $ F \subseteq F(\alpha) \subseteq K $. The Tower Law then asserts that

$$ [F(\alpha):F][K:F(\alpha)] = [K:F] $$

Since $ K/F $ is finite, by definition the RHS is finite. On the other hand, it is seen from the above equality that $ [F(\alpha):F] $ is less than or equal to $ [K:F] $, therefore is also finite. By definition, $ \alpha $ is algebraic over $ F $.

Answer (score 0):

As other have said, by definition, a field extension $K$ over $F$ is of finite degree if and only if it is finitely generated, because its degree $n$, by definition, is the minimum number of vectors $v_1,v_2,...v_n \in K$ (from the field extension $K$) that are sufficient to form a spanning set over the underlying field $F$. I.e. if the degree is finite, then a finite number of vectors are enough, and so our extension is finitely generated and conversely, if we can finitely generate our extension, then by definition, the field extension / vector space $K$ has a finite degree equal to the number of vectors we need.

However, regarding the second part of your question about all finite extensions being algebraic:

I believe a lot of common proofs I have seen for this statement online rest on unjustified premises. Therefore, I will now share what I think is an elegant, elementary and self-sufficient actual proof from:

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Size_of_Linearly_Independent_Subset_is_at_Most_Size_of_Finite_Generator

Let $K$ be a finitely generated vector space / extension over $F$. This means that we can find a finite number of vectors in $K$ that will span $K$ by drawing coefficients over $F$.

Let $ v_1, v_2, ..., v_n$ be such a spanning set for $K$ over $F$ (called a basis for $K$ over $F$). This means, we define $n$ to be the lowest positive integer for the number of vectors that are required to span $K$ over $F$.

Let $x_1, x_2, ..., x_r \in K $ be a sequence non-zero vectors s.t. $r>n$. We will prove that these vectors **must** be linearly dependent by contradiction! So let us begin by assuming that they are indeed an independent collection of vectors.

We know that there exist $a_1, a_2, ..., a_n \in F$ s.t.

$$ x_1 = a_1v_1 + a_2v_2 + ... + a_nv_n$$

Therefore the elements in the finite sequence $\{x_1, v_1, v_2, v_3, ..., v_n\}$ are linearly dependent. Now consider this beautiful idea: starting from the left-most term and going right-wards, let "$a_i$" be the first term from this ordered sequence that can be expressed as a linear combination of some terms strictly to the left of itself! This term can not be $x_1$ as we have positioned it as the first term in the sequence and so by definition, it cannot be composed of any elements preceding it (as no entries precede it).

Note: Since $x_1$ can, however be expressed as a linear combination of some of the subsequent terms of our sequence (which span $K$), we know that in any case, we will eventually encounter some $i \in \{1,2,3,...,n\}$ s.t. $a_i$ will satisfy our criterion. If $1 \leq j_1 < j_2 < ... j_f \leq n$ are the integer indices s.t. $a_{j_1},a_{j_2},...,a_{j_f} \in F$ are all non-zero and:
$$ x_1 = a_{j_1}v_{j_1} + a_{j_2}v_{j_2} + ... + a_{j_f}v_{j_f}$$

holds. Then exactly $i = j_f$ will be the index that we are looking for, as we can write $v_{j_f}$ as a linear combination of the following preceding terms:

$$ a_{j_f}^{-1}(x_1 - a_{j_1}v_{j_1} - a_{j_2}v_{j_2} - ... - a_{j_{f-1}}v_{j_{f-1}})= v_{j_f} = v_i$$

We will throw this now superfluous term "$v_i$" out of our sequence and we will still have a spanning collection of $n$ vectors (you can easily show that this new sequence of vectors yields a basis). So now we have $S_1 = \{x_1, v_1, v_2, v_3, ..., v_n\}$.

Now, inductively, we repeat the same procedure. Consider the sequence of $n+1$ terms: $\{x_2,x_1, v_1, v_2, ...,v_{i-1},v_{i+1},..., v_n\}$. We repeat our argument: $x_2$ can not be a linear combination of any vectors to the left of it as there are no preceding terms in our sequence. On a different note, now: by our assumption of independence for the vectors $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$, $x_1$ cannot possibly be a linear combination of the vectors coming before it. Eventually we must, however come across the term we are searching for as $x_2$ can be written as a linear combination of terms from $S_1$. So we drop the redundant term and we get $S_2 = \{x_2,x_1, v_1, ..., v_n\}$ which is, again, $n$ terms long, as we have added $x_1$ and $x_2$ (2 terms) and have dropped 2 of our original basis vectors.

Inductively, we then repeat this argument until we get our final sequence of basis vectors $S_n = \{x_n,x_{n-1},...,x_2,x_1\}$. Now, recall that we have assumed that $r>n$, so we still have some vectors $x_{n+1},x_{n+2},...,x_{r}$ left. However, since our vectors from the final sequence $S_n$ span $K$, we can express  any of these remaining extra vectors as a linear combination of the vectors $x_1,...,x_n$. Therefore, we have directly contradicted our assumption that $x_1,...,x_r$ are linearly independent. Therefore, we have shown that for a finite extension of degree $n$, any collection of $r$ vectors where $r>n$ are going to be linearly dependent. Now letting $\alpha \in K$, we see that a non-trivial solution to:

$0 = a_0 + a_1\alpha + a_2\alpha^2 + ... + a_n\alpha^n$

must exist by the linear dependence of $1,\alpha, \alpha^2, ..., \alpha^n$ (as here we have $n+1 > n$ terms). Hence every term of a field extension of finite degree is algebraic; i.e. a finitely generated extension / an extension of finite degree is algebraic.