# What does $[\mathbb{Q}(a):\mathbb{Q}(b)]$ mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I saw the above in a Number Theory textbook, when they were providing an alternate solution to a problem. They said it was a "more conceptual, but much more advanced" way to solve the problem.

"Let $\displaystyle x=\cos \left(\frac{2\pi m}{n} \right)$ and $\displaystyle z= \exp \left( \frac{2i\pi m}{n} \right)$, then

$$[\mathbb{Q}(z):\mathbb{Q}(x)]=2$$

What does this notation mean? Or if it would take too long to explain, where can I find out what it means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, $\mathbb{Q}(z)$ denotes the smallest field over $\mathbb{Q}$ that also contains the element $z$, and likewise for $\mathbb{Q}(x)$.  In the context of the problem, we have $\mathbb{Q}(x) \subset \mathbb{Q}(z)$.  Mathematicians might say that $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ is a "subfield" of $\mathbb{Q}(z)$, or alternatively, that $\mathbb{Q}(z)$ is a "field extension" of $\mathbb{Q}(x)$.

---

As far as the bracket notation goes, this says that you can view $\mathbb{Q}(z)$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ wherein the dimension of that vector space is $2$.

That is to say, we can find a two-element basis $\{a_1, a_2\} \subset \mathbb{Q}(z)$ such that any arbitrary element $y \in \mathbb{Q}(z)$ can be written in the form $y = c_1a_1 + c_2a_2$ for some $c_1, c_2 \in \mathbb{Q}(x)$.

As an example, consider the quadratic extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ of $\mathbb{Q}$.  This extension field has a basis $\{1, \sqrt{2} \}$, and so any element $x \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ can be written in the form $x = a + b \sqrt{2}$ for $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$.  Hence, we write $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q}] = 2$.

---

As a side note, the following theorems can greatly simplify the process of determining this value:

- Suppose you have a field extension $F(a)$ over a field $F$.  If $f(x) \in F[x]$ (the ring of polynomials with coefficients in $F$) is an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ with $a$ as a root, then $[F(a):F] = n$.
- Suppose you have a tower of fields $F \subset E \subset K$.  Then $[K:F] = [K:E] \cdot [E:F]$.

Comment: Don't omit that $\textbf{a}$ is in the "catch-all" field $K$.

Comment: Thanks dude, your answer exceeded my expectations

Comment: @extremeaxe5, I'm glad I could help!  Feel free to ask about anything that's still unclear (I don't know how much algebra you've seen, so I tried to cover as many bases as possible without going into too much detail in any one place).

Comment: @Rod, what do you mean?

Comment: $F \subseteq K$ is an extension of fields and you consider $a \in K$ to be algebraic over $F$. Then $F \subseteq F(a)$ is a finite extension.

Comment: Oh yes!  That is true (somewhat encoded in the first theorem).  What's more, $[K:F]$ is finite if and only if every element of $K$ is algebraic over $F$.  See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/773955/is-any-finite-dimensional-extension-of-a-field-say-f-algebraic-and-finitely/773965

Comment: Yup that is true, just induction on the elements that you take to roots of polys in $F$, but I don't think algebraic extensions need to be discussed here lol.

Comment: @KajHansen oh one more question, how would you verbally say: [Q(sqrt2):Q]=2 ?

Comment: @extremeaxe5, I say "The degree of Q adjoin the square root of 2 over Q".  In general for an extension field $K$ of $F$, I'll say $[K:F]$ verbally as "the degree of $K$ over $F$".